# Facebook SDK: Post scores without publish_actions or another alternative?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, sdk

I am using the Facebook SDK Score system to post the scores that the users have on my game.

However, to do so, the users must approve the publish_actions request (which pretty much nobody does :P).

I have seen lots of other games that keep scores without requesting publish_actions.

How can I do it?? Or at least modify the message that publish_actions gives to the user (to say that I only want to post the scores to the servers and not to their timeline)

(the game is made with Unity 3D 4.6)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the share /feed dialog to publish these posts. This prompts a user to post a story instead of implicitly publishing after getting permissions. The user can still choose to not share this post, but you at least more flexibility this way.

A sample call looks like :

```
FB.Feed(
    link: "https://example.com/myapp/?storyID=thelarch",
    linkName: "The Larch",
    linkCaption: "I thought up a witty tagline about larches",
    linkDescription: "There are a lot of larch trees around here, aren't there?",
    picture: "https://example.com/myapp/assets/1/larch.jpg",
    callback: LogCallback
);
```

Also, this is a good read for what else you can publish with it.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Feed

Comment: well that doesn't really help me though. The whole game is based on high scores so they must be posted every time they happen. Now that I think about it I could use an outside database server and store all the scores there (however getting them this way - with facebook - is way more easier and convenient)

Answer (score 0):

Like above answer share is good option. If your application is seems trsted to users means they will give user permission to your app. Try to get that permission, You only need to get user access one time. For sharing post every time it asks users, so user may not accept that.